# Saving one entity having m-t-m relationship duplicate the other entity in the DB?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two entities with many to many relationship, I'm saving one entity that has a list of entities, but they get duplicated
ex:

```
class GENEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<GENEntityTab> tabs { get; set; }
}
class GENEntityTab
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<GENEntity> entities { get; set; }
}
```

When I save object of `GENEntity` but as a view model as you'll see next, with a list of two `GENEntityTab`, those two tabs get inserted (duplicated) in the DB. I'm using Web API and angular

In the Repository, it's only called when I click submit (there are some extra properties):

```
  public static JsonViewData AddOrUpdate(ModelDBContext context, GENEntityViewModel entityVM, string name, string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = context.Entities.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == entityVM.Id);

            if (entity == null)
            {
                entity = new GENEntity();
                entity.InjectFrom(entityVM);
                context.Entities.Add(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                entity.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
                entity.InjectFrom(entityVM);
            }
            entity.CreatedById = new Guid(id);
            entity.LastUpdatedById = new Guid(id);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return new JsonViewData { IsSuccess = true, Message = "Created Successfully" };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new JsonViewData { IsSuccess = false, Message = ex.Message };
        }
    }
```

the view models:

```
public class GENEntityTabViewModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<GENEntity> Entities { get; set; } = new List<GENEntity>();

        public GENEntityTabViewModel()
        {

        }

        public GENEntityTabViewModel(GENEntityTab entityTab)
        {
            Id = entityTab.Id;
            Name = entityTab.Name;
            Description = entityTab.Description;
            Entities = entityTab.Entities;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's only class definitions. Please show code which you are using to save `Entity` objects

Comment: I amended my question